# How do i display the first item in the already?

Tags: c#, winforms

How do i display already the first item from the comboBox ?
The combobox look empty only when i click on it to collapse the list i see the list of items.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            {
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Reduced by: " + i.ToString());
            }
```

Comment: Set the SelectedIndex property to 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean to select the first item in the combobox you can do this:

```
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `SelectedIndex` and set it to 0:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add("Reduced by: " + i.ToString());
}
comboBox1.SelectedIndex=0;
```

Read more about [**ComboBox.SelectedIndex Property**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).